# How to get rid of this weird box on my page?

Tags: css, validation, firebug, html

A weird box suddenly appears in the background of my site [link](http://cheapgamessales.com/product/1001-MiniGolf-Challenge.html).

[Image http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p769/Stonecold_Stone/page_zps0c289fe8.png](http://i1350.photobucket.com/albums/p769/Stonecold_Stone/page_zps0c289fe8.png)

Firebug identifies it as `<pre id="line1"><span>` and it seems to be causing some of the [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://cheapgamessales.com/product/1001-MiniGolf-Challenge.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services) too, like:

> Element div not allowed as child of element span in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

I thought the problem would be easily fixed by editing out the id `line1`, but I searched over the CSS files and there's no such id called "line1".

Comment: Well, there is a `<pre id="line"`> that you can remove if you want, but that is not the cause of the validation error. You have `<span><div class = 'pto_product'>` on the same line, that;'s where the error comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of the **pre** tag check the picture bellow

you can fixed it by adding this to your style

**option:1**

```
#line1{
background: transparent!important;
border: 1px solid transparent!important;
}
```

or search for that pre tag and close it

**option:2**

```
<pre id=line1> </pre>
```

**option:3**

go to style.css on the **line 129**

and edit it

this s all cooollll webpage :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's in `http://cheapgamessales.com/wp-content/themes/Pronto/style.css?ver=3.6` line: `130` the property `background: #eee;` is giving this background color to the element `<pre>`

Comment: Thanks for identifying the culprit. The problem is gone.